# How to pass sql query with sql variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass following sql query in php

```
SET @rank=0; SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, `percentage_obtained`  FROM `result`  ORDER BY percentage_obtained DESC
```

As here

```
mysql_query('SET @rank=0; SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, `percentage_obtained`  FROM `result`  ORDER BY percentage_obtained DESC') or die(mysql_error());
```

But it throws following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT `@rank`:=`@rank`+1 AS rank, `percentage_obtained` FROM
>   `result` ' at line 1

However it works when I run the query directly inside the database. Please assist.

Comment: I have an idea that this - @rank:=@rank is a problem, because it is a digit. It provides like this - SELECT 4 AS rank etc.

Comment: But this give right out put when I use it directly inside the MySQL db

Comment: Please do a print_r(your query); and post here. Also you set @rank=0, and then do an increment. Why don't do a SELECT 1 ?

Comment: Found the answer )

Comment: Here it is:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, percentage_obtained FROM  result ' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

**mysql_query()** doesn't support multiple queries, so you need to separate them.
Also you can use **mysqli_multi_query** - but note, that you need **mysqli** instead of **mysql**

So

```
mysql_query('SET @rank=0') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, `percentage_obtained`  FROM `result`  ORDER BY percentage_obtained DESC') or die(mysql_error());
```

should handle this

Comment: Thank you, But how can I do it?

Comment: Just split into 2 queries

Comment: Then it says:  No database selected

Comment: Use mysql_select_db ('your database'); before queries.

Comment: Database is already connected; it out put single queries without any errors.

Comment: Second one: mysql_query('SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, `percentage_obtained`  FROM `result`  ORDER BY percentage_obtained DESC') or die(mysql_error());